# Meteor app with multiple, separate client apps

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to build a Meteor App which, for some clients, is very sensitive to HTML and JS payload.

Is there any way or recommended practice in Meteor to build separate clients, so that only certain HTML, JS and CSS will be bundled for each client (and maybe some of it common to all of them, shipped to all of them)?

Other than building separate Meteor apps with a shared database, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, incremental loading is not a feature in meteor but it is [under consideration](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading) for a post-1.0 release.

A number of us who host production apps are grumbling about this. One proposed solution (which I have not yet tried) is to use the upcoming [ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/meteor-core/XDWx5kscddY/discussion) in combination with a [reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003689/recommended-nginx-configuration-for-meteor) to divide apps by path. Even if that works, its a complex hack and still requires breaking your codebase into separate apps.

Sorry, I wish I had better news. At the minimum, you could get vocal on trello about your need for this feature.

Comment: Thanks David, this was useful. I didn't know Meteor roadmap planning was out there on Trello. I included my concerns in the Trello card for this issue and voted, hoping that will help eventually have the feature available.