# Multiple MeteorJS clients in one project

Tags: meteor

Is there any way of creating multiple meteor clients on one server? What I mean is having multiple, distinct, client applications that all communicate with the same server? So, a data change at www.mainapp.com will show up in www.companionapp.com and vice versa.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way of creating multiple meteor clients on one server?

Yes, you can host them behind a reverse proxy like [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003689/recommended-nginx-configuration-for-meteor).

> What I mean is having multiple, distinct, client applications that all communicate with the same server? So, a data change at www.mainapp.com will show up in www.companionapp.com and vice versa.

Yes, as long as all of the apps are started with the name `MONGO_URL`, then they will share the same database (and therefore simultaneously reflect its changes).

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple distinct applications that use the same DDP connection so that data is shared reactively across applications.

To share a DDP connection:

Main App (running on port 3000):

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");

if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.publish("posts", function(){
        return Posts.find({});
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient){
    Posts.subscribe("posts");
}
```

Companion App (running on port 3030):

```
var conn = DDP.connect("http://localhost:3000");
Pictures = new Meteor.Collection("pictures", conn);

if(Meteor.isClient){
    conn.subscribe("posts");
}
```

If you're running both apps on the same box you'll need to specify different ports for each app:

```
meteor --port 3030
```

[Server 2 Server DDP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtCfRyJGlAk) A pretty entertaining youtube video from Alan Shaw, that this answer is based off.

And I'd recommend reading Meteorhacks' [Introduction to DDP](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-ddp.html)

NOTE: DDP connections only work through websockets, so if you have a proxy in between you'll run into issues