# How to run meteor on a different port

Tags: meteor

How to run meteor on a different port, for example on port 80.
I tried to use `meteor --port 80`, but I get this error `Error: listen EACCES`

help me please.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: `sudo meteor --port 80`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports)

Comment: please check the very detailed answers from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/CBOatiMOj5c

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like it might be access issue on your machine.

Check out this following answer, which might be related to your question.  Quoting:

"As as a general rule processes running without root privileges cannot bind to ports below 1024.

So try a higher port, or run with elevated privileges via `sudo`."

So, you can see that `sudo meteor run` with your port number will work, but that you can address the root cause, which is fixing the node root privilege.

[Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports)

Answer (score 10):

You can't bind to ports < 1024 on Linux/Unix operating systems with a non-privileged account.

You *could* get around this by running meteor as root, but this is a really bad idea. In development mode, running as root will modify the permissions of the files under your application directory. In production, it's just a giant security hole. **Never run a meteor app as root**.

Listed below are the best practices depending on your environment.

### Development

Run meteor on a high port number. The default is 3000 when you don't give a `--port` argument. Connect to it via the URL printed in the console - e.g. `http://localhost:3000/`.

### Production

Here you have two choices:

- Run meteor on a high port number and connect it to the outside world via a reverse proxy like [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003689/recommended-nginx-configuration-for-meteor) or [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).
- *Start* the webserver as root but step down the permissions once it's running using something like [userdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/userdown). This is how [mup](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) works which, incidentally, is probably what you should be using to deploy your app.

Answer (score 5):

The `meteor run --port 8080` terminal command can be used.

Answer (score 3):

run it with sudo

```
sudo meteor --port 80
```

Comment: Its a huge security leak to run it with sudo. I'd give -10 for such "solutions"...

Comment: @PawełSmołka Can you explain me how it is security leak with sudo as I am newbie to ubuntu.Thanks

Comment: For example: If someone will hack your webapp he may gain root access to your server and call system commands remotely. I am also not an allmighty expert but I am very carefull about running with root rights any app with public access...

Comment: Meteor installs on your local user and running on sudo will probably won't work or have unintended consequences, -10.