# Meteor App only appears on :3000 in Nginx with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, meteor, digital-ocean

I am deploying a Meteor App (Telescope) on my Ubuntu server running nginx - I got everything set up and working but the site will only show if I go to http://mysite.example:3000 rather than mysite.example

I am pretty new to Nginx and tried playing around with a Virtual Host file in the sites-available & sites-enabled folders but I don't think this is the way to go.

How can I get my app to appear on my sites default ports rather than :3000?

Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run meteor on a different port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027454/how-to-run-meteor-on-a-different-port)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be some misconfiguration in the virtual hosts file. Are you passing all your requests to meteor?

```
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
}
```