# Retrieving data from webpage using script and then accessing it with node js server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I have a html file `index.html` with a local script `script.js` running in `localhost:8080` using a script `NodeServer.js` in `Node.js`.

> I want that, whenever I **enter data** in input boxes, it should get
>   fetched by the *local script* and then the `script.js` export it to
>   the `NodeServer.js` application, which would further log the data on the
>   console.
>
> I am using Chrome browser - `65.0.3325.181`

Here is my `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Website</title>
    <!-- My local script -->
  <script src='file:///F:/RahulVerma/NodeJS/LoginPage/script.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Enter username' id='username'/><br/>
  <input type='password' placeholder='Enter password' id='password'/><hr/>
    <!-- getData() is present in local script -->
  <button onclick='getData();'>Submit</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `script.js`:

```js
let getData = () => {
 let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
 let password = document.getElementById('password').value;

 module.exports = { username, password }; // exporting username and password to server running through node.js
}
```

And my `NodeServer.js`:

```js
const http = require('http'); // to create server
const fs = require('fs'); // to read index.html
const script = require('F:/RahulVerma/NodeJS/LoginPage/script'); // to fetch data from script.js

// My Server
let server = (request, response) => {
 fs.readFile('F:/RahulVerma/NodeJS/LoginPage/index.html', 'utf8', (error, result) => {
  if(error) {
   response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.write(`Error: ${error}`);
  } else {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   response.write(result);
  }

  response.end();
 });
}

// Creating server
http.createServer(server).listen(8080);
console.log(script.username, script.password); // logging data onto the console
```

When I type node NodeServer.js in Node.js 9.3.0 (ia32) and npm, the `index.html` starts working on `localhost:8080` but the `script.js` fails to render in the browser due to the following error: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///F:/RahulVerma/NodeJS/LoginPage/script.js`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

cors error:a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access selected resources from a server on a different origin

```
// Create our server
var server;
server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
// Set CORS headers
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");;
if ( req.method === 'OPTIONS' ) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
    return;
}
});
```

further clarification visit [stack overflow cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124600/how-can-i-add-cors-headers-to-a-static-connect-server)

Best awnser [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr)

Comment: Can you provide me this code inside `NodeServer.js` code?

Comment: copy paste whatever inside is inside my server object ,before your fs.readFile